# Second order pde in 2 variables

Tags: partial-differential-equations

How I find the general solution of $u_{xx}-u_{yy}+\dfrac {2u_x}x=0$ equation by $w=x^nu$ transform?

Comment: did i edit the question correctly?

Comment: I would have interpreted the first-order term differently, but you may be correct.  We need the OP to clarify.

Answer (score 2):

We have

$$u_{xx} - u_{yy} + \frac{2 u_{x}}{x} = 0$$

Setting $w(x,y) = x^{n} u(x,y)$ and differentiating with respect to $x$, we get

\begin{align}
w_{x} &= n x^{n-1} u + x^{n} u_{x} \\
\implies w_{xx} &= n (n-1) x^{n-2} u + n x^{n-1} u_{x} + n x^{n-1} u_{x} + x^{n} u_{xx} \\
&= n (n-1) \frac{x^{n} u}{x^{2}} + n x^{n} \frac{2 u_{x}}{x} + x^{n} u_{xx} \\
\implies \frac{w_{xx}}{x^{n}} &= n (n-1) \frac{u}{x^{2}} + n \frac{2 u_{x}}{x} + u_{xx}
\end{align}

Notice that if we set $n=1$ we get

\begin{align}
\frac{w_{xx}}{x} &= \frac{2 u_{x}}{x} + u_{xx}
\end{align}

where the RHS is just what we have in our original PDE. Similarly for the $y$ derivatives, we find

\begin{align}
w_{y} &= x^{n} u_{y} \\
w_{yy} &= x^{n} u_{yy} \\
\implies \frac{w_{yy}}{x^{n}} &= u_{yy} \\
\implies \frac{w_{yy}}{x} &= u_{yy}
\end{align}

where in the last line we set $n=1$ as before. Hence, we can rewrite our PDE

$$u_{xx} - u_{yy} + \frac{2 u_{x}}{x} = 0$$

as

\begin{align}
\frac{w_{xx}}{x} - \frac{w_{yy}}{x} &= 0 \\
\implies w_{xx} - w_{yy} &= 0
\end{align}

which can be solved using separation of variables.

Comment: Yeah, you've edited correctly. Thanks for solution :) I found something similar to that but I used chain rule. Firstly I took U alone and then I calculated Uxx and Uyy. So you don't need to say 1 for n. Because in the solution should be n. I am not sure if I find Uyy correctly :/